# Hudson update doesn't download "svn:externals" projects

Tags: tortoisesvn, hudson, svn-externals

I have a project which has one subfolder. This subfolder has 3 children folders:

```
D:\MainFolder
|---SubFolder
    |----ChildrenFolder1
    |----ChildrenFolder2
    |----ChildrenFolder3
```

SVN Externals was set using Tortoise. When I use Update from context menu in Windows, everything is downloaded correctly. But the problem is with Hudson update process.

It is not downloading externals into ChildrenFolder1, ChildrenFolder2 and ChildrenFolder3. Is there a configuration missing somewhere in hudson to instruct correct downloading?

The `svn:externals` configuration set in Tortoise for D:\MainFolder is:

```
\SubFolder\\ChildrenFolder1 svn://externalproject1/trunk/ChildrenFolder1
\SubFolder\\ChildrenFolder2 svn://externalproject2/trunk/ChildrenFolder2
\SubFolder\\ChildrenFolder3 svn://externalproject3/trunk/ChildrenFolder3
```

Comment: I've also had Hudson quietly fail to download "svn:externals" when they're on a different svn server than the main repo, and that svn server is running a version of svnserve that isn't compatible with the SVNKit the Hudson subversion plugin was made from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I had for this issue was

1) Configure Hudson Subversion client:

[image]

2) Using Tortoise "Repo browser", remove `svn:externals` from D:\MainFolder
and set `svn:externals` to the D:\MainFolder\SubFolder.

```
ChildrenFolder1 svn://externalproject1/trunk/ChildrenFolder1
ChildrenFolder2 svn://externalproject2/trunk/ChildrenFolder2
ChildrenFolder3 svn://externalproject3/trunk/ChildrenFolder3
```

Now the path problem is gone:

```
ERROR: Failed to update http://externalproject1/trunk
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: Invalid svn:externals property on '': target '/SubFolder/ChildrenFolder1' is an absolute path or involves '..'
```

Answer (score 0):

We had what sounds like the same problem with Hudson silently failing to download properly configured svn:externals.  I solved the problem based on the comment from Jack Ace at [svn:externals not being checked out](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-8312). I reset our credentials for the external repository and then it started working.